# Defining a conditional statement as a variable

Tags: c

I am attempting to use a variable to store a conditional statement's result:

```
int age = 40;
int validAge = age > 40;

if (validAge) { /* ... */ }
```

Is the above code example allowed in C? If so, what type should I set these conditional variables?

Comment: `char` in C is an integer type. Why does it feel wrong?

Comment: @axiac As a C novice I was not aware of this, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I think @axiac is just saying that it isn't "obvious" why it should feel wrong. Once you realize that `age > 40` evaluates to, effectively, a boolean true/false, _regardless of the type_ of `age` and `40`, there's no reason why the result should be stored in an `int`

Comment: You can even store the value [0|1] of `validAge` in a bitfield of length one (within a structure). :-)

Comment: @TimRandall Yes I do understand what was being implied, my misunderstanding came from my past belief that `char` itself couldn't represent a false value as my previous assumption was that it could only contain a character that always evaluates to true, equivalent to strings in other languages.

Comment: It actually not a bad question at all to introduce new C programmers to the fact that a conditional can be use as an expression (in any capacity where an expression is valid) including in assignment to an lvalue.

Comment: For clarity, I would choose type `_Bool` for the result, but of course any integer type works.

Comment: The result of a relational expression is either 0 or 1 and has type `int` ([C 2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.5.8, clause 6).  You should be able to store the result in any integral type (or, as of C99, `_Bool`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid.

The expression `age > 40` evaluates to either 0 or 1, so you can use any integer type (`char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, either signed or unsigned) to store it.

Comment: Perfect answer, will accept in a few minutes. Thanks.

Comment: This is all because C does not have a native boolean type, so any integer type will do the business. 0 is false, and /any other value/ is true.

Comment: @GemTaylor C does have a native boolean type called `_Bool`.

Comment: And in C99 or later, another option is `_Bool`, aka `bool` if `<stdbool.h>` is included (which also defines `true` and `false`, and another housekeeping macro).

Comment: Ok, probably should have said "did not have". :-)

Comment: @GemTaylor yes that distinction is important. **C** has a native boolean type, called `_Bool`. C90, which is an obsolete version of the language that should never be called "C" without qualification, did not, but that's really not very relevant in this day and age, even for embedded and legacy work.

Comment: @Leushenko Is it, though? C is very much stuck with maintaining compatibility with 50+-rear-old code that did not have a bool, and does not give the bool type any sort of primacy in the way that C++ does. Yes, the named type _Bool exists, but it doesn't have any real special powers.

Comment: @Leushenko - only in ivory towers, which includes a lot of the membership here.  C90 is still very much used in large real world projects.  Updating compilers, and versions of a language, comes with a cost (documentation, V&V, etc) so large/huge real-world projects remain slow in updating which version of standard they comply with.  And they will remain slow until the cost/benefit ratio of updating - as evaluated, for example, by company accountants, not developers - is sufficient to justify accepting the code.

Comment: @Peter this is purely anecdotal, but we've found prospective customers tend to get very dismissive if we even mention that our frontend still supports C90 (as though it's a bad thing to support multiple language versions...). It seems to be C11 or nothing if you want to be taken seriously in the embedded world these days.

Comment: @Leushenko - your prospective customers, almost by definition, will be inclined to give priority to updated and new features.  Almost by definition, developers involved with large projects that are costly to update, will not have that priority.   If you want to attract those sorts of customers, you'll need to emphasis life cycle benefits (e.g. a measurable benefit or mitigated cost of updating and then sustaining their product versus remaining locked in as they are).  Not impossible, but different from presenting the latest features.